# ng-options clears the model (and visible options) on click, what in tarnation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here is my ng-options markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Client(s)</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="addFirm.firmData.clients" ng-options="clients.instance.id as clients.instance.fName for clients in addFirm.firmData.clients" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the resulting html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Client(s)</label>
    <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="addFirm.firmData.clients" ng-options="clients.instance.id as clients.instance.fName for clients in addFirm.firmData.clients" multiple="" aria-invalid="false">
        <option label="Mike" value="string:567f82a9b6daa74f16547564">Mike</option>
        <option label="brian" value="string:567f83ac61b2fe4160fb4d4a">brian</option>
        <option label="Bill" value="string:567f8df461b2fe4160fb4d4b">Bill</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Everything looks good but the moment I click on the select menu to pick one, let alone a few, the model is cleared which results in the options being completely wiped out. Any idea what might be happening? I have no rouge click events lying about and the rest of the form, which includes about 15 other standard text fields, functions fine.

The really odd thing is if I do a standard select tag with an ng-repeat, I get none of that hogwash. This works fine:

```
<select name="clients" id="clients" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="clients in addFirm.firmData.clients" value="{{clients.instance.id}}">{{clients.instance.fName}}</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding select to the *same model* you use to store array items:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="addFirm.firmData.clients" <!-- <-- addFirm.firmData.clients -->
    ng-options="clients.instance.id as clients.instance.fName for clients in addFirm.firmData.clients" multiple>
                                                       <!-- and here again --^ -->
</select>
```

See, `addFirm.firmData.clients` is both in `ngModel` and `ngOptions`? Bind ngModel to something else, for example:

```
ng-model="addFirm.firmData.clientSelected"
```